# Modern File Structuring for Website Development

Tags: indexing, web, directory, structure

So I am fairly new to website development, PHP, Mysql, etc. so it's a given if I get some downvotes for my sheer lack of intelligence, I just want the answer haha.

I have *probably* jumped the band wagon or probably inherited a completely bad coding practice; instead of simplistic website structures such as **stackoverflow.com/questions.php?q=ask** (displaying content based on GET data), or making it even more simplistic such as **stackoverflow.com/ask.php**, etc, we have the seemingly straight forward  **stackoverflow.com/questions/ask**

So what's the weird magic going on?

Comment: search for URL rewriting

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you're looking for [mod_rewrite](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/).

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite will work but it really won't improve your actual file structure on the site (behind the scenes.)

For that you would use a PHP framework. I would suggest starting with [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com) which is simpler than Zend. (I don't have experience with CakePHP so I won't comment on that.)

You will need to configure routing to trap a url so that it maps to a certain *controller* the use a function to capture the rest of the url as parameters.

```
function _remap($params = array()) {
    return call_user_func_array(array($this, 'index'), $params);
}
```

Then, in the same controller change the index function like this:

```
function index($id = null) {
    $data['question'] = /* get your data from the database */;
    $this->load->view('index', $data);
    return true;
}
```

This assumes you started with the welcome controller example in the zip file.

But, to answer your question more directly, there isn't really any magic going on. The browser is requesting a certain resource and the server is returning that resource according to it's own logic and how it is configured.  The layout of files on the server is an internal issue, the browser only sees the representation of the server's state.  Read up on the REST principle to understand this better.